# Memory leaks when deleting row from a tableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-leaks

I am loading data from a plist into a tableview in my application. Data is stored in a mutable dictionary of mutable dictionaries.
Here is my viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Categories";

    // load data from plist fle
    self.categories = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InventoryItems" ofType:@"plist"]] autorelease];

    // add buttons to navigation menu
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.addButton;
}
```

My tableview is editable, so user can delete categories. In my commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: method I update my data model:

```
[self.categories removeObjectForKey: [[self.categories allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

When I profile my app it leaks memory. I am not very proficient in using the profile tool, but it seems to find leaks in my categories dictionary every time I delete a row.

I wonder where I missed releasing something? Is it a problem that object I am removing is a dictionary as well and I need to remove its objects too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This leaks (if the property is retain or copy):

```
self.categories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InventoryItems" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

Use this instead:

```
categories = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InventoryItems" ofType:@"plist"]];
```

or this:

```
self.categories = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InventoryItems" ofType:@"plist"]] autorelease];
```

Comment: the reason behind the leak is that the init creates a retain count of 1, and the retain on the property also creates a retain count of 1, giving you a retain count of 2 when you only expected 1.  leak.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I added autorelease for self.categories, still have the same problem though. The Leaked Objects include: _NSCFDictionary and NSCFString.

Comment: @Shvetusya you have shown us how you create your dictionary and how you remove objects from it but in between you must use these objects to display data in your table view. Maybe you over-retain those objects (just guessing).

Comment: Had to start project all over again but figured it out!

Comment: @albertamg yeah the problem was in the code in-between; each category had dictionary of items and i didnt dealloc items property correctly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this would give you anything different?

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:
                                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"InventoryItems" ofType:@"plist"]];

self.categories = d;
[d release];
```